# Rails route based on virtual host (Host HTTP header)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, virtualhost

Is it possible to specify a Ruby on Rails route based on the host part of the request URL?

In config/routes.rb, I have

```
root :to => 'entities#index'
```

but I would like to use the same code base to serve several sites, each with their own default controller.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use [Request Base Constraints](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#request-based-constraints)

```
root :to => "siteone#index", :constraints => {:host => "siteone"}
root :to => "sitetwo#index", :constraints => {:host => "sitetwo"}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Also remember to put these constraints BEFORE your unconstrained "root" line, because they're handled in order. 

And another gotcha I ran into was that you can't test the new routing on the local server unless your "siteone" domain DNS is configured to point to your localhost. Once you get it right and deploy to production, you'll need to reconfigure your DNS to point to your production server.

Comment: @AminAriana you could test the routing locally, without modifying DNS servers, by adding the hostname in the constraint to your /etc/hosts file with the local IP (127.0.0.1)

Comment: @Eero: Thanks, you're right, I remember that from Windows. But I was on a Mac and wasn't familiar with how to do that. Looks like there's a way: http://decoding.wordpress.com/2009/04/06/how-to-edit-the-hosts-file-in-mac-os-x-leopard/ ... but I opted for changing it from the DNS server. This way my code heirs won't have to spoof their machines.

Comment: is it possible to do this using a header other than "Host"? maybe a custom header such as "APIVersion"?!?

Comment: @Leonardo the list of methods you can use are here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#the-request-object but they need to return a String, base on the documentation for http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#request-based-constraints